# Using UUID to get Device Locations

Tags: javascript, cordova

Using Cordova, Javascript, and css: is it possible to use a device's UUID number to get its' location?

For example, I have different UUID numbers stored in a database and want to use them to locate the devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. UDID only can get from iTune. If you want retrieve device id can, using pushplugin phonegap plugin.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/08/29/implement-push-notifications-for-android-and-ios-phonegap-part-1/